# 2mm pitch 10pin header (2x5) to 2.5mm pitch socket connector header adapter

Tags: pcb, connector, pins, adapter

My PCB has a 2.0mm pitch 10pin JTAG header (2x5). My MIPS programmer has a common 14-pin(2x7) 2.5mm pitch socket connector header at the end (flat IDC cable with female header). How do I interface them? Is there special Breakout Board adapter for this?
[image]

Comment: Proto-advantage

Comment: Is it for JTAG? Search for "JTAG adapter". Or go to https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33011125916.html

Comment: @Codo yes, for JTAG. Yes, sort of Jtag adapter/pitch changer, from 10pin 2mm pitch to 14pin 2.5mm pitch. But how this adapter will match custom 10-pin layout to 14-pin layout.

Comment: The adapter on AliExpress includes both a 14pin 2.54mm connector (middle black one) as well as 10pin 2mm connector (smallest black one). So it should work. You can verify the correct wiring with the bottom side PCB picture. The matching 10-pin cable might be missing.

Comment: The key thing is how to set correct wiring on PCB JTAG header: for this the 10-pin cable should be "Flywire" type (individual wires with single female connector sockets 2mm pitch) on the one end.

Answer (score 1):

These are commonly called "pitch changer" adapters. You may or may not be able to find one that suits your needs. If you can't find one, you can make a suitable cable yourself. All you need is a piece of ribbon cable, the sockets for either end and the appropriate crimping tool for whatever sockets you choose.

Comment: What would be the appropriate pitch for the ribbon cable?

Comment: Anything works, 1.27mm is the most common. You'll have to separate the wires at the ends anyway (or at least at the 2mm end if you want to use a crimp-on connector for the 2.54mm end, these accept 1.27mm pitch ribbon cables)